# Run-time error '33' Despite correct ChomeDriver, Selenium/Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vb.net, selenium

Trying to get started with Selenium/Excel VBA to do some scraping. Cannot get started due to Run-time error '33'.

Search only revealed one case where the problem was addressed by matching Selenium Version with correct ChromeDriver Version.  I've done that with .75 and .74 Chrome browser versions, and corresponding correct ChromeDriver version.  Same error regardless.

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()

Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
bot.Get "/"
bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/screenshot.jpg")
bot.Quit
'quit method for closing browser instance.
End Sub'
```

`bot.Start` line elicits Run-time error '33'.

> Run-time error '33':
>
>
> SessionNotCreatedErro
>
> session not created exception
>
> from unkown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context"
>
> {"auxData":{frameId":"D306.......1C","isD
>
>
> (session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)"

Currently

ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140

Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build)

Windows 10 Pro, 1809

Selenium Basic 2.0.9.0

Excel 360, 64 Bit